# The imp module is deprecated in favor of importlib but lock_held() is missing

Tags: python, python-3.x

If we run the following python command we see that `imp` is deprecated:

```
$ python -We -c "import imp;imp.lock_held()"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/imp.py", line 31, in <module>
    warnings.warn("the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; "
DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
```

Trying this using `importlib` gives the following:

```
$ python -We -c "import importlib;importlib.lock_held()"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'importlib' has no attribute 'lock_held'
```

Doing some poking around we see that `lock_held` lives in a "private" module:

```
$ python -We -c "import _imp;_imp.lock_held()"
```

So to get rid of the `DeprecationWarning` is that what we are expected to do ? Should we switch to using `_imp` even though it is "private" ?

Comment: In most cases, you should try to avoid using private modules or functions.